# Change Timezone in oracle apex 5.1

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

How can I change the default timezone in oracle apex 5.1 to my current timezone ?
I tried changing the Automatic Timezone setting in Globalization but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Apex says that "When set to Yes, the **client time zone is derived from the client's Web browser** and set for the duration of the Application Express session.". So, what does your web browser say?

Answer (score 0):

The step you are following is correct to display date & time according to User's timezone. But in addition to this, you have to consider `LOCALTIMESTAMP` instead of `SYSDATE`(for the source of Item if you are displaying time).

If you are taking Page Item based on Table Column, you have to define data type of you table column as `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` instead of `DATE`. This will instruct Apex to take/convert date & time according to User's (Browser's actually) timezone.

---

for detail please consider below step.

1. Set datatype of Table Column as TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE.

   `CREATED_ON     TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE,`
2. In Page Process or Trigger, use LOCALTIMESTAMP instead of SYSDATE to feed value.

   `:NEW.CREATED_ON := LOCALTIMESTAMP;`
3. Set Application Automatic Time Zone = 'Yes'

   - Application Builder -> Select Your Application -> Edit Globalization Attributes -> Automatic Time Zone -> Select 'Yes' -> Apply Changes.

Answer (score 0):

**SELECT LOCALTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;**

USER DATE TYPE "LOCALTIMESTAMP" FOR YOUR'S NEEDED TIEMZONE

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You only show code. Please write some English prose to make a complete answer. Consider using this info to format your code as code, instead of as a mixture of bold and unbold caps. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help